# WPF приложение с постраничной навигацией

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Кто знает, где можно посмотреть подробный пример WPF или WPF Prism приложения с постраничной навигацией, организованной по типу мастера в Windows? Чтобы с кнопками "Вперед"/ "Назад"/"Готово". То что нашел - просто подмена  View при нажатии на кнопку, в первом приближении похоже, но  из руководства по Prism следует, что для таких приложений предполагается использование навигационного сервиса и навигационного журнала.
Нашел неплохой пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466890/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-mvvm-light?rq=1), но он для MVVM Light. 
У меня это первая проба организовать постраничную навигацию, так что пример хотелось бы подробный.
Мой проект предполагает одну большую  вью-модель, которая будет последовательно заполняться данными на нескольких окнах.

Comment: Например, так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740529/10105

Comment: @VladD: Пытался сделать по схеме по ссылке. Не получается переход. Как лучше будет: мне вопрос апдейтить с кодом или попытаться объяснить на  пальцах что не работает?

Comment: Лучше пример с кодом, конечно. Поскольку на этот вопрос уже есть ответ, может быть, имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @VladD Вынес в отдельный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803527/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иметь одну viewmodel для всех страниц не очень хорошая идея. Вы нарушаете принцип паттерна MVVM. Гораздо лучшим подходом будет иметь некий бизнес-объект, выделенный в отдельный класс, инстанс которого вы будете передавать каждой viewModel через dependency injection.

При таком подходе у вас не возникнет проблем с навигацией, поскольку использование сервиса навигации отлично ложится на такую архитектуру. Вы можете навигироваться на один и тот же регион многократно, заменяя активное представление. При этом вам будет доступна история и вы сможете вызывать навигацию на шаг назад через тот же самый сервис навигации.

Comment: "Иметь одну viewmodel для всех страниц не очень хорошая идея. Вы нарушаете принцип паттерна MVVM" Справедливости ради MVVM не единственный паттерн при работе с WPF

Comment: Вы правы, это я неправильно выразился. Будет именно так, как Вы написали.  Будет одна сущность, которая будет заполняться на  наверное  десятке страниц.

Comment: Тогда какая у вас проблема?

Comment: @AntonShakalo проблема - как сделать навигацию со страницы на страницу. Вопрос не столько в том, как я буду тянуть сущность со страницы на страницу , сколько как сделать навигационный сервис.

Comment: @Foggy Если уж мы говорим о вью-модели в вопросе, скорее всего автор использует именно MVVM, так что ответ в контексте MVVM вполне ок.

Comment: @foxhound вам не нужно делать навигационный сервис, prism уже всё сделал за вас https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Navigation.html

Comment: @VladD контекст следующий: "одну большую вью-модель, которая будет последовательно заполняться данными на нескольких окнах." можно читать как один большой источник данных разбитый на компоненты.